# Is there a way to have a custom humanize result for certain symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When displaying symbol values to a user, I know you can make them more human-readable by doing something like

```
my_symbol.to_s.humanize
```

Is there a way to customize the result of that call for certain symbols? For most cases it works fine, but there are times when it isn't quite what you want. For example, if I had a status field with options Queued, Sent, Re-sent, etc. I can use symbols `:queued` and `:sent`, but what about for Re-sent? `:resent` or `:re_sent` would be good enough for coding, but the humanized forms are not good enough for displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-human)

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> :re_sent.to_s.humanize 
=> "Re sent"
irb(main):002:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en).human(/re_sent/, "Re-sent") 
=> [[/re_sent/, "Re-sent"]]
irb(main):003:0> :re_sent.to_s.humanize
=> "Re-sent"
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the proper place to add these is to config/initializers/inflections.rb